# Python page view API missing data

Tags: python

I wrote code to find page views daily from wikipedia articles and for one case, for the month of January, there is no entry for Jan-3rd and Jan-10th. Im assuming this means there are no page views for that day so I hard coded entries for those days at 0 views, but the code won't be dynamic in that case. Does no entry into the list for a certain day mean there are no views for that day or is it a data grab error?

```
page_list = []
for name in names:
    page_views = pageviewapi.per_article(lang, name, start, end, access = access, agent = agent, granularity = granularity)   
    page_list.append(page_views)

print(page_list[8]['items'][0:12)

[{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 5}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010200', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 4}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010400', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 5}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010500', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 8}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010600', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 4}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010700', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 5}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010800', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 15}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020010900', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 4}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020011100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 7}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020011200', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 5}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020011300', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 3}, 
{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Citi_Bank', 'granularity': 'daily', 'timestamp': '2020011400', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'all-agents', 'views': 21}]
```

You can see here that the 3rd and 10th are not in the list. How would I code a try/except sequence to check for missing data entries?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _Does no entry into the list for a certain day mean there are no views for that day or is it a data grab error?_ That information might be in the API docs. _How would I code a try/except sequence to check for missing data entries?_ Do you get an error when the page view data is missing?

Comment: That is the example. I run that code and this is the list i receive. No error, just no entry for January 3rd and January 10th. Names is just a list of other banks and i gave the range 0:12 to show how the entries do not exist. City Bank is page_list[8] and the ['items'] is just to clear some other jargon out of the output. Look at the timestamp to see missing dates. (YYYYMMDD00) and ignore the last two zeroes.

Comment: _No error, just no entry for January 3rd and January 10th._ Then a try-except is probably not the best choice. Are you using Pandas for this?

Comment: Yes, I was considering an if/else but I don't know the format of what the exception should look like. I can't find documentation for missing entries.

Comment: _Yes, I was considering an if/else but I don't know the format of what the exception should look like._ Can you be more specific about which part you're struggling with? Have you tried writing pseudocode, or something like that?

Comment: I need to write dynamic code which can tell if there is an entry missing in order, because the 3rd and 10th of january do not show up. This messes with my date indexing. if this happens with another query i am gathering, i need dynamic code to recognize this and make a placeholder entry. If you look at my code u can see those dates are missing. How do I account for this issue with any query i make?

Comment: You could generate all the dates between your start and end date, and use that to check if you're missing data for any of the days.